# Get string for translation

Tags: android, string, translate

I have my app working this way:

```
public static String formatForUI(Calendar today, Calendar date) {
    if (today.get(Calendar.YEAR) == date.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
        if (today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) {
            return "Today";
        }
        return currentYearDateFormat(date.getTimeInMillis());
    } else {
        return format(date.getTimeInMillis());
    }
}
```

I want the "Today" to be a string, so I have it in the strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="today">Today</string>
</resources>
```

Also I have the es\strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="today">Hoy</string>
</resources>
```

I've tried with getResources() but it doesn't work. How can I do it?

Comment: "but it doesn't work" define doesn't work.

Comment: It says "cannot resolve symbol"

Answer (score 3):

As for many things in android, you need a `Context`. Typically, your Activity or Service, or the Activity containing your Fragment.

Define the method to expect a Context parameter:

```
public static String formatForUI(Context context, Calendar today, Calendar date) {
```

Then use the context:

```
return context.getString(R.string.today);
```

(or `context.getResources().getString(R.string.today)`, and with the resources you can access other things beside strings)

Comment: Or just `context.getString()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solutions:

- Clean and build your android project should work.
- If not, try to restart android studio.
- If you still got error, put `getcontext().getResources().getstring(int id)`.

Comment: The last bullet doesn't make any sense. Please edit it.

Comment: Hi @Code-Apprentice Thank for comment. I have delete the last bullet because it doesn't answer the problem.